# Can't update table 'Bids' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the Tables

```
CREATE TABLE Bids
 (buyer VARCHAR(20),
 vin VARCHAR(20),
 amount int,
 autobid int,
 upperlimit int,
 PRIMARY KEY(buyer, vin, amount),
 FOREIGN KEY (vin) REFERENCES Auctions(vin)

 );

 CREATE TABLE Notifications
 (buyer VARCHAR(20),
 outbidded VARCHAR(20),
 vin VARCHAR(20),
 amount int,
 PRIMARY KEY(vin, buyer, amount)
 );
```

And the triggers

```
 DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_bid_insert 
    BEFORE INSERT ON Bids
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

    SELECT B.amount, B.buyer INTO @amount, @buyer
    FROM Bids AS B WHERE B.vin = NEW.vin AND B.amount = (SELECT MAX(amount) FROM Bids B WHERE B.vin = NEW.vin AND B.buyer != NEW.buyer);

    IF NEW.amount > @amount  THEN
    INSERT INTO Notifications (buyer, outbidded, vin, amount)
    values (NEW.buyer, @buyer, NEW.vin, NEW.amount);


    END IF ;


END$$
DELIMITER ;

 DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER automatic_bidding
    AFTER INSERT ON Notifications
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

    SELECT B.amount, B.buyer, B.autobid, B.upperlimit INTO @amount, @buyer, @autobid, @upperlimit
    FROM Bids AS B WHERE B.vin = NEW.vin AND B.amount = (SELECT MAX(amount) FROM Bids B WHERE B.vin = NEW.vin AND B.buyer != NEW.buyer);

    IF NEW.amount > @amount AND @autobid != 0 AND NEW.amount + @autobid <= @upperlimit THEN

    SET @amount = NEW.amount + @autobid;

    INSERT INTO Bids (buyer, vin, amount, autobid, upperlimit)
    values (@buyer, NEW.vin, @amount, @autobid, @upperlimit);


    END IF ;


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But I keep getting this error. The first trigger is supposed to add a notification to the notification table that a user has been outbid. The automatic bid trigger is then supposed to react on this, and check if the user who was out bid had an autobid set, which will then place a new bid. However, it seems that mysql won't allow this because the first trigger is using the bids table to do its operation? How could I separate the two actions so that they can work off of each other?

edit: I tried changing the notifications table to include info from the bids table, so that I could operate  the 2nd trigger from notifications instead of Bids, but it still did not help. Same error, not working still

Comment: It's not possible to do this using triggers. You might consider delegating this to your front end if you have one or using a procedure rather than an insert.

Comment: Thanks, I had to implement one of the triggers in JSP instead